# Cassandra, how twitter handle like and retweet count

Tags: cassandra

I guess twitter is or was using Cassandra. Below is sample of twitter tweet table based from their design. My question is how do they handle like and retweet count When it is strongly advisable in Cassandra not to use int type for count, rather counter should be used.

```
CREATE TABLE tweet (
  tweetid bigint,
  post text,
  like_count int
  retweet_count int
);
```